# Women in Toldos Aharon Chassidut

Tags: chasidut-hasidism

I really enjoy the Toldos Aharon Chassidus, the way the are totally focused in Torah, Avodah and Guemach. So i'd like to know if they have a midreshet? I found on Google their Yeshiva and kollel beir yossef that are open for male foreing students, but didn't found nothing about women.

Comment: Thank you @Nosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Toldos Aharon Chassidus (to the best of my knowledge) has a highschool for girls but there is no formal post high school study program. This is likely due to the fact that girls in this community generally get married at about 18/19 years of age. In the Israeli Chareidi world in general girls highschools have grade 13 and 14 during which girls train for various professions and unlike in the American Chareidi world, girls do not attend a separate seminary (or midereshet) after highschool.